# NPM Doesn't Work - Windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, npm

[Npm Doesn't Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liAui.jpg) I tried "run administrator command prompt" or "uninstall and install nodejs" or "[add path to environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKM2D.jpg)". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it looks like you might be on the right track with system variables, this can occur when temp variables are either duplicated or wrong..

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7590